# Implement Likebutton with PHP,MySQL and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to include a Like button, would like to use Ajax for this.

I coded it normally with PHP, but with Ajax it is much much better.

my add_like returns the value 1, I don't get the current number of likes nor is the PHP code executed.

Where is my error? How do I run the like button and output the current likes?

**Javascirpt:**

```
            e.preventDefault();
            var like = $("#threadLike").val();
 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'add_like.php?page=<?php echo $page; ?>$like=<?php echo $page; ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {like: like},
                success: function(data){
                    if (data == 1) {
                        loadData();
                    }else {
                        alert("Not working");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP & MySQL:

```
session_start();
include("assets/include/config.php");
$userid =  $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
 
    if(isset($_GET['like'])){
    //Subcomment Page ID
    $linkedId = $_GET['like'];
 
        if($linkedId == $page){
        //Überprüfe ob ich schon Geliket habe
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, commentId, userid, created_at FROM subThreadLikes WHERE commentId = ? AND userid = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$linkedId, $userid]);
        $rowCountSubThreadLikes = $stmt->rowCount();
 
 
        //Wieviele User haben das Thread geliket?
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT subThreadsID, userlike FROM subthreads WHERE subThreadsID = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$page]);
        $rowAllUserLiked = $stmt->fetch();
        $allUserLiked = $rowAllUserLiked['userlike'];
 
        //Wenn kein Like vorhanden, gebe dem Thread ein Like
        if($rowCountSubThreadLikes == 0){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subThreadLikes (commentId, userid) VALUES (?,?)");
        $stmt->execute([$linkedId, $userid]);
 
        //Aktualisiere die Spalte in der Datenbank
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE subthreads SET userlike = ? WHERE subThreadsID = ?");
        $result = $stmt->execute([$allUserLiked+1, $page]);
 
            if ($result) {
                echo 1;
            }else {
                echo 0;
            }
 
        }
 
 
        //Wenn Likes vorhaden sind, löscht von der Datenbank einen Like
        if($rowCountSubThreadLikes == 1){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM subThreadLikes WHERE commentId = ? AND userid = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$linkedId, $userid]);
 
 
        //Aktualisiere die Spalte in der Datenbank
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE subthreads SET userlike = ? WHERE subThreadsID = ?");
        $result = $stmt->execute([$allUserLiked-1, $page]);
 
            if ($result) {
                echo 1;
            }else {
                echo 0;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" id="threadLike" style="font-size: 15px"><i class="fas fa-angle-up" style="color: <?php echo $color; ?> "></i> <span style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $likedThema; ?></span></a></div>
                
 
<div class="threadLikeBox" id="threadLikeBox">
```

Comment: `...$like=<?php echo $page; ?>` should most likely be `...&like=<?php echo $page; ?>`. (Should the `like` parameter also have a value of `$page`? Kind of redundant)

Comment: Thanks! It's work